# mysql count all id given in where clause and count rest of the remaining

Tags: mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm

I want a list where i can get count of my given id's in where clause, and the count of remaining id's as rest here is my query:

```
Select cat.name AS name, COUNT(cat.name) AS total
FROM MyAppBundle:Content c INNER JOIN c.category cat
WHERE cat.id IN(11,7,16,1,12,13)
GROUP BY cat.name;
```

but dont know how to get the rest total, can anyone help?

Comment: Please review the answers given below, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can combine `SUM` and `CASE` to get both the matching and non-matching counts:

```
SELECT cat.name AS name,
    SUM(CASE WHEN ID IN (11,7,16,1,12,13) THEN 1 ELSE 0) AS countMatch,
    SUM(CASE WHEN ID NOT IN (11,7,16,1,12,13) THEN 1 ELSE 0) AS countNotMatch
FROM MyAppBundle:Content c INNER JOIN c.category cat
GROUP BY cat.name
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use UNION ALL:

```
Select cat.name AS name, COUNT(cat.name) AS total 
FROM MyAppBundle:Content c INNER JOIN c.category cat 
WHERE cat.id IN(11,7,16,1,12,13)  
GROUP BY cat.name
UNION ALL
Select 'OTHERS' AS name, COUNT(cat.name) AS total 
FROM MyAppBundle:Content c INNER JOIN c.category cat 
WHERE cat.id NOT IN(11,7,16,1,12,13)
```

Answer (score 0):

try as below-

```
SELECT cat.name AS NAME, 
COUNT(IF(cat.id IN (11,7,16,1,12,13),id,NULL)) AS matching_row, 
COUNT(IF(cat.id NOT IN (11,7,16,1,12,13),id,NULL)) AS non_matching_row
FROM content as c INNER JOIN category as cat on c.id=cat.content_id
GROUP BY cat.name;
```

where I am assuming that category table contains join field content_id if it is not the case the change c.id=cat.content_id as per your join condition.

Even in your query there is no need of join with content table if you don't want to check matching rows in this table.

Comment: I am getting this error:

Error: Expected Doctrine\ORM\Query\Lexer::T_CLOSE_PARENTHESIS, got '('

Comment: $query = $this->getEntityManager()->createQuery(
            'SELECT cat.name AS NAME,
COUNT(IF(cat.id IN (11,7,16,1,12,13),id,NULL)) AS matching_row,
COUNT(IF(cat.id NOT IN (11,7,16,1,12,13),id,NULL)) AS non_matching_row
FROM MyAppBundle:Content c INNER JOIN c.category cat
GROUP BY cat.name');

Comment: i thing your table names are content and category so use as I have updated in my answer.